# Como implementar um destrutor em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, ecmascript-6

Em linguagens como C++, temos a possibilidade de declarar um destrutor para uma classe, para que determinadas ações sejam realizadas quando um objeto dessa classe é destruído. Como fazer isso em JavaScript? Por exemplo:

```js
class minhaClasse {
  constructor(elem){
    this.elem = elem;
    this.elem.addEventListener("click", this.acao);
  }
  acao(){
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "Clicado !<br/>";
  }
  
  destrutor(){
    this.elem.removeEventListener("click", this.acao);
  }
  
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(even){ 
  
  var obj = new minhaClasse(document.getElementById("bt"));
document.getElementById("bt2").addEventListener("click",function(){
    obj.destrutor();
    delete obj;
    
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="bt">Clique</button>
<button id="bt2">Deletar</button>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Tem como remover o evento sem precisar chamar o método `.destrutor()`, ou seja, isso ser feito automaticamente quando ou objeto é deletado ou *garbage-collected*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A única forma é chamar na mão mesmo. Seu código está correto e terá que será assim.

Não há nenhum recurso disponível na linguagem que permita isso. E até onde sei não há previsão de ter. Isso provavelmente é uma falha.

Veja se [isso](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/1289665) te ajuda. Note que você pode economizar uma linha, mas ainda precisa deletar o objeto explicitamente, o que não é o mesmo que o C++ faz.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).